# Using .each() to run separate function when the element is totally in view

Tags: jquery, css, each

I am having a bit of trouble getting the code to only run for one instance of the class at a time.

I know this code works when using an element with just one instance, such as an ID as I have previously used it. However, this time I am trying to use the same function multiple times initiating at different times (when each element is scrolled over).

I also know this is close, it runs, and adds the class, only to all of the instances not one at a time as it is scrolled into view.

I can see myself running around in circles trying to explain this so here is my code, please let me know if you need help understanding the code. Im hoping it is just a simple concept I have misconstrued.

```js
(function($) {

    //CHECK SCROLLED INTO VIEW UTIL
    function Utils() {

    }

    Utils.prototype = {
        constructor: Utils,
        isElementInView: function (element, fullyInView) {
            var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
            var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
            var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();

            if (fullyInView === true) {
                return ((pageTop < elementTop) && (pageBottom > elementBottom));
            } else {
                return ((elementTop <= pageBottom) && (elementBottom >= pageTop));
            }
        }
    };

    var Utils = new Utils();
    //END CHECK SCROLLED INTO VIEW UTIL

    //USING THE ELEMENT IN VIEW UTIL
    //this function tells what to do do when the element is or isnt in view.
    //var inView = Utils.isElementInView(el, false); Where FALSE means the element doesnt need to be completely in view / TRUE would mean the element needs to be completely in view
    function IsEInView(el) {
    
        var inView = Utils.isElementInView(el, false);

        if(inView) {

            if (el.hasClass('open')) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                el.addClass('open');
            }

        } else {
            //console.log('not in view');
        }

    };

    //Check to make sure the element you want to be sure is visible is present on the page
    var variableOfYourElement = $('.timeline-point');
    console.log(variableOfYourElement);

    //if it is on this page run the function that checks to see if it is partially or fully in view
    if( variableOfYourElement.length ) {

        variableOfYourElement.each(function(){

            el = $(this);

            //run function on page load
            IsEInView(el);

            //run function if the element scrolls into view
            $(window).scroll(function(){

                IsEInView(el);

            });

        })

    }
    //END USING THE ELEMENT IN VIEW UTIL

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.massive-spacer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1234px;
    background-color: pink;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box!important;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}   
    .section-inner {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1248px;
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;

        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: stretch;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

/* ------------------- */

.timeline {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.timeline-point {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
    .timeline-point.open {
        background-color: purple;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="massive-spacer"></div>

<div class="section about-history-section">
    <div class="section-inner">
        <div class="timeline">
            <div class="timeline-point">a</div>
            <div class="timeline-point">b</div>
            <div class="timeline-point">c</div>
            <div class="timeline-point">d</div>
            <div class="timeline-point">e</div>
            <div class="timeline-point">f</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="massive-spacer"></div>
```

I appreciate the snippet maybe doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted some of the CSS that was irrevelant to the current problem and simplified your code a bit (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This is what I ended up with. It is important that you bind the scrolling event to the `window` object but check for each of the `.timeline-point`-divs Whether they are (fully) visible (for the demo I chose "fully" visible, as it is easier to track here). `if(isInView(el,1)) $(el).addClass('open')` will add the class "open" to the class-list permanently whenever `isInView()` returns `true`.

[[Please be aware that the code will not run in Internet Explorer, as it doesn't support the ES6 arrow functions, but if you change them to "normal" functions it should work there too.]]

```js
function isInView(element, fullyInView) {
  var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
  var elementTop = $(element).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(element).height();
  // use a ternary operator ( ? : ) here to apply one of two possible tests
  // and return result directly
  return ( fullyInView 
           ? pageTop < elementTop && pageBottom > elementBottom
           : elementTop <= pageBottom && elementBottom >= pageTop );
};
// bind scroll event to window object:
$(window).scroll(()=>$('.timeline-point').each((i,el)=>{ // for each div do ...
  if(isInView(el,1)) $(el).addClass('open') 
}));
```

```css
.massive-spacer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
}
* { position: relative;}
.timeline-point {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center
}
.timeline-point.open {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="massive-spacer"></div>

<div class="section about-history-section">
 <div class="section-inner">
  <div class="timeline">
   <div class="timeline-point">a</div>
   <div class="timeline-point">b</div>
   <div class="timeline-point">c</div>
   <div class="timeline-point">d</div>
   <div class="timeline-point">e</div>
   <div class="timeline-point">f</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class="massive-spacer"></div>
```

You can write it even shorter by slightly changing your `isInView()`-function into `setOpenClass(i,el)` like:

```
function setOpenClass(i,el) {
  var pageTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height();
  var elementTop = $(el).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(el).height();
  if( true // = fullyInView 
     ? pageTop < elementTop && pageBottom > elementBottom
     : elementTop <= pageBottom && elementBottom >= pageTop) $(el).addClass('open')
};
// bind scroll event to window object:
$(window).scroll(()=>$('.timeline-point').each(setOpenClass));
```

Comment: smashed it lad! Could I be cheeky and ask you to help me keep the open class once applied. I need it to remain attached to the element once it has happened once.

Comment: If you could notify me when youve updated c: Also I like to double up on the cheek. Would you be able to comment the code slightly so I can follow your logic, youve condensed my code into about 1/4 of the size... #mindbent

Comment: Thats some serious code you've given me buddy. Massive thank you! Please upvote if you enjoyed my question c: